# Terminology: a --------- Product of Semi-Rings?

Tags: measure-theory, notation, terminology

I'm looking for the correct term to describe a product of semi-rings. If $\mathscr S_1, \mathscr S_2$ are semi-rings on sets $X_1, X_2$ respectively then $\mathscr S = \{S_1 \times S_2 : S_1 \in \mathscr S_1 ,  S_2 \in \mathscr S_2\}$ is a semi-ring on $X_1 \times X_2$. It is the -------- product of $\mathscr S_1, \mathscr S_2$ ?

In "Introduction to Measure and Integration" - S. J. Taylor p.134, he calls it a "Product of Classes"
In "Measure Theory" - P.R. Halmos, he uses the construction (on Rings) but doesn't name it
In "Real Analysis: Theory of Measure and Integration" - Yeh p.527 he seems to refer to it as a Cartesian product.

Would it be correct to view this as a tensor product and represent it as $\mathscr S_1 \otimes \mathscr S_2$ ? (This would seem to follow the same approach as for sigma algebras.)

Comment: For $\sigma$-algebras, I think people usually just call it "the product $\sigma$-algebra", with the definite article,  and denote it with either $\times$ or $\otimes$ according to author preference.  I've never heard them attach an adjective like "tensor, Cartesian, cross, direct", etc.  It's analogous to "the product topology".  So I would just call it "the product semi-ring", and use either $\times$ or $\otimes$ as you prefer.

Comment: @NateEldredge It's not the product sigma algebra though. The product sigma algebra is generated by such a collection.